# Renting in Denmark. Landlord wants to adjust the price according to CPI

Tags: rental, denmark

I have been renting an apartment in Denmark for almost a half a year. Recently, the landlord contacted me asking to resign the contract, because of an oversight: they did not include rent price adjustment according to CPI for each year. He sent me the new contract with the new paragraph:

```
Lejen fastsættes i henhold til boligreguleringslovens § 5, stk. 2. Lejer erklærer sig ved sin
underskrift af nærværende lejekontrakt enig i, at den i nærværende lejekontrakt fastsatte husleje 
svarer til det lejedes værdi. 

Den til enhver tid gældende leje reguleres hvert år med virkning fra den 1/1, første gang 1. 
januar 2017 med den procentvise stigning i nettoprisindekset fra oktober måned i det foregående 
år til oktober måned året forud. Pristalsreguleringen sker af den umiddelbart før 
reguleringstidspunktet gældende leje. Den årlige regulering gennemføres alene ved udlejers 
skriftlige meddelelse til lejer. Udover pristalsreguleringen, reguleres lejen med eventuelle 
ændringer i skatter og afgifter jf. LL § 50-51.
```

He asked me to sign ASAP, but this sounds a bit fishy, so I asked for some time to check. Is this a normal practice in DK and should I sign?

It is hard for me to figure this out, especially since I do not speak Danish, and have few friends here who rent.

I do not mind the adjustment; according to my calculations, it was about 40 dkk for the last year. It doesn't look like a problem, but I do not want to aleinate my landlord. At the time, I don't trust my landlord enough to sign everything he asks.

Comment: I have not rented in Denmark recently. However, based on casual googling, this type of regulation appears to be normal for newer contracts, and is explicitly allowed by law, although I can’t vouch for the exact language you are quoting. But you are not really obligated to sign, it is something that has to be in the original contract. Is the contract based on the [standard form](http://uim.dk/filer/bolig/typeformular-a.pdf)?